# SQL group by multiple columns with a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there a quicker way to group by multiple columns in SQL than the query below?

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,sum(c1) as sum_c1 from table_a 
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

for example: if one needs to group by 50+ columns and doesnt want to type 1-50 can you group by a range.. like `group by range(50)`  ? does anything like this exist in SQL?

**I am using postgreSQL

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Please don't use column ordinals in your `GROUP BY`... that's just lazy, confusing, easy to break, and hard to maintain.  In your current example, you could just copy/paste the select list into your `GROUP BY`.  It's not difficult.

Comment: @Siyual i hear you but when you have multiple joins and clunky column names, it makes the code cleaner...

Comment: @ziggy - `cleaner` code has nothing to do with it being `efficient`. But if you really want it, you can use a dynamic SQL to generate it. I don't think you can do it anyway by plain SQL.

Comment: @Utsav okay y'all are probably more experienced with SQL than I am so I will take your advice on this

Comment: @ziggy It really doesn't... It's much, *much* dirtier to use ordinals.  You're forcing the reader (and yourself) to read the ordinal number, then count out which column that maps to.  It's *much* cleaner to explicitly write the name of the column.  On top of that, if something changes in the query and the `SELECT` list is changed, you'll have to invest a large amount of time trying to figure out what the new ordinals are.  And the last point... if you *need* to include *every* column in your `GROUP BY`, you should really re-evaluate your query...

Comment: @Siyual points taken, I understand why it would be harder to retrace the ordinals if the query changes. in terms of including all my columns in the group by, that is not the case in my actual query I am working on, but my table will have 50+ columns because I am creating a summary table of landuse acreage for about 50+ landuse types broken down by statewide parcels

Comment: @Siyual Or maybe the OP should reconsider the database design itself.  I don't see too many queries on SO or in real life which select so many columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was originally using python for the summary table creation but that got clunky and it was real slow. so I started writing it in postgreSQL/postgis and its way faster and the column names are cleaner, its just an enormous QRY